# sqlite matching text only with LIKE and not with =

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a table that was created using Pandas DataFrame.to_sql().

According to the documentation, 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = "Some text";' is how you search for an exact match to a text field.  However, here's what I'm getting:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test WHERE textfield = "Some text"
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test WHERE textfield LIKE "%Some text"
1|Some text
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test WHERE textfield LIKE "Some text%"
1|Some text
```

I'd rather not use LIKE because I know there's going to be more overhead.  Clearly it's not an issue with invisible characters because the LIKE versions match, and return the same rows, regardless of where I put the wildcard.

When I try using data I entered manually, it matches just fine.  So there seems to be something weird about the data inserted by Python/Pandas.  I can't tell what, though.  Some sort of encoding issue maybe?

So what's going on, and is there a more efficient fix than using LIKE?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27

Comment: No, I can't reproduce it in a sqlite fiddle.  As I said, if I enter the data manually (natively) in sqlite, it works just fine.  It's this data that was inserted by Pandas that won't match.  And I can't seem to find a fiddle that supports Pandas; pythonfiddle.com just hangs.

If there were a nonprintable character before the text, "Some text%" wouldn't match it.  If there were one after the text, "%Some text" wouldn't match it.  Both do.